# Backup/Restore System Folders on new VM

Tags: vmware

I'm looking for a safe option for taking an image of my machine cuz I'm in a place where I cannot risk trying anything isn't safe and the machine must be up and running. For example, clonezilla looks a good option but I haven't tried it before and I cannot risk booting from a live CD on the same machine.

On my previous post:
[Take an Image of a Physical Machine using VMWare Converter Standalone - Options diabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601960/take-an-image-of-a-physical-machine-using-vmware-converter-standalone-options)

I'm looking for a solution for the issues I came across with VMware Converter or any other suggestions. In this post I want to ask you guys what do you think of the following idea:

1. Creating a virtual machine of Ubuntu using VMware Workstation.
2. Backing up my folders of the origial server using backintime-gnome http://backintime.le-web.org/
3. Restorung these folders on the new VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... You did not like my previous answer? ;)

Still you should provide us with more details about your partitions:

```
lsblk
df -h|grep /dev/
```

Using complex software doesn't make the process more safe. Linux is about combining the most simple software to do the most complex tasks.

Having that in mind, I show you how to do exactly what you want but with basic software:

- create empty disk image `fallocate -l (max disk size)G disk.img`
- partition image `fdisk disk.img`
- create loopback device for image `kpartx -a disk.img` so we can access the partions
- format partition `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/loop0p1`
- create mountpoint `mkdir /media/mountpoint`
- `mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /media/mountpoint`
- copy all files from source system to image `sudo cp -a (TODO?) / /media/mountpoint/`
- `umount /dev/mapper/loop0p1`
- delete loopback device `kpartx -d disk.img`
- TODO: install grub to image
- convert image to vmdk `qemu-img convert -f raw -O vmdk disk.img disk.vmdk`

I will go into more detail if you approve you want to try this solution and provide more info on your partitions.

This will only require 2 times the space as your system really occupies, not of the disk size. 
In the vm you first have to boot a linux live system to install grub and make the disk bootable.

Comment: Sorry I just saw your answer and replayed providing more information. Thanks a lot!